# Doubt in really elementary algebraic geometry definitions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying [Shafarevich's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540548122) and I didn't understand the motivations behind this definition:

[image]

In theorem 4, the author says this definition is the same of the one he previously defined:

[image]

It seems redundant a new definition of regular rational functions, what's the motivation behind this?

Thanks

Comment: But a rational function might _not_ be regular at every point...?

Comment: Global vs. local. A function is continuous ..., a function is continuous at a point ... .

Comment: Maybe one way to clarify it would be to avoid using the same word for two different things. So in the second definition, one could change the term "regular" (which is being defined here) to anything else you like --- let's say "nice". Then Theorem 4 would say "A rational function such that... is a nice function on this set." Now do you think there is any redundancy?

Answer (score 3):

If you are knowledgeable in complex analysis, substitute "regular'' with "holomorphic" and "rational" with "meromorphic". Then, consider the theorem:

> A meromorphic function which is holomorphic at every point of some set is a holomorphic function in some neighborhood of this set.

Hopefully this is analogous enough for you.